# Extra lines being printed based on earlier input datatype

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop

My question is about how this program handles unexpected inputs. It seems to work fine except when a string is entered.

When one inputs a string into coin, the message "*Please enter a valid input*" appears and main is run again, which is expected. Then when one of the amounts in coins is entered correctly, the program spits out the proper input, but for each time an incorrect string was entered earlier, it seems to 'remember' and prints "*Thank you for your patronage, you paid: 0 CAD*". So for example, the following terminal session will occur:

> Please select a coin value in pennies (No toonies allowed): asd
>   Please enter a valid input
>   Please select a coin value in pennies (No toonies allowed): hmm
>   Please enter a valid input
>   Please select a coin value in pennies (No toonies allowed): 100
>   Thank you for your patronage, you paid: 100 c CAD
>   Thank you for your patronage, you paid: 0 c CAD
>   Thank you for your patronage, you paid: 0 c CAD

I only want the statement regarding 100c to show up. **I don't understand what is causing the code to '*remember*' the string inputs.** The code is below, I am really stumped as to why this is happening. When the else statement in `coinamount()` is ran, shouldn't the program effectively '*restart*' as if I had just run the code, since the user input is being reassigned with a new prompt?

```
coins = [0, 5, 10, 25, 100]

def coinamount(total):
    coin = (input("Please select a coin value in pennies (No toonies   allowed): "))

    if coin == "q":
        print("Quitting...")

    elif coin.isnumeric():
        coin = int(coin)
        total += coin

    else:
        print("Please enter a valid input")
        main()

    return total


def verification(coin):
    if coin in coins:
        print("Thank you for your patronage, you paid:", coin, "c CAD")

    elif coin == 200:
        print("I told you we don't accept toonies...")
        main()

    else:
        print("Please enter a valid coin amount")
        main()


def main():
    tab = 0
    tabplus = coinamount(tab)
    verification(tabplus)

main()
```

Comment: That's because you (incorrectly) use recursion for the task. Please *don't*.

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing loops and recursion. When you program runs right now it is doing this:

```
main()
 |
 ---> coinamount()
        |
        ---> main()
              |
              ---> coinamount()
                     |
                     ---> ...
```

That's not what you want in your program. It's a little bit unclear what your program should be doing, but I would imagine it's something more `main` calls `coinamount` and `coinamount` loops until it gets a valid input and returns that valid input to `main`.

If you want main to keep running until the user presses q, then add a loop into main as well.

One possible implementation is below:

```
coins = [0, 5, 10, 25, 100]

def coinamount(total):
    while True:
        coin = (input("Please select a coin value in pennies (No toonies allowed): "))
        if coin == "q":
            print("Quitting...")
            return coin
        elif coin.isnumeric():
            coin = int(coin)
            total += coin
            return total
        else:
            print("Please enter a valid input")

def verification(coin):
    if coin in coins:
        print("Thank you for your patronage, you paid:", coin, "c CAD")
    elif coin == 200:
        print("I told you we don't accept toonies...")
    else:
        print("Please enter a valid coin amount")


def main():
    tabplus = coinamount(0)
    while tabplus != "q":
        verification(tabplus)
        tabplus = coinamount(tabplus)

main()
```